# Why is deadlock alert not working?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, alerts, event-notification

I created a deadlock alert including notification to an operator like this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'1205 Deadlock', 
        @message_id=1205, 
        @severity=0, 
        @enabled=1, 
        @delay_between_responses=30, 
        @include_event_description_in=1, 
        @database_name=N'myDB', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized]', 
        @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
```

This alert is registered for notification.

It's history says it never appeared although it is in place for months and there are multiple deadlocks per day. I created a deadlock manually. It shows up in the Log File.

What is missing for this alert to raise a notification? 
Other notifications like e.g. 18456 Invalid Login work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the error 1205 is not set up to be logged in `ERRORLOG`. Look it up in `sys.messages`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.messages 
WHERE message_id = 1205;
```

If the column `is_event_logged` is set to 0, change it this way:

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_altermessage 
    @message_id = 1205,
    @parameter = 'WITH_LOG',
    @parameter_value = 'true';
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189531.aspx) for `sp_add_alert` describes under which conditions an alert is raised:

> ### Remarks
>
> **sp_add_alert** must be run from the **msdb** database.
>
> These are the circumstances under which errors/messages generated by SQL Server and SQL Server applications are sent to the Windows application log and can therefore raise alerts:
>
> - Severity 19 or higher **sys.messages** errors
> - Any `RAISERROR` statement invoked with `WITH LOG` syntax
> - Any **sys.messages** error modified or created using **sp_altermessage**
> - Any event logged using **xp_logevent**

Comment: Is there any reason not to do this? For example, causing the ERRORLOG to grow?
I want to be cautious and not break anything on production

Comment: Unless you have an inordinate amount of deadlocks happening, this won't make any difference on your ERRORLOG size. However, in modern versions of SQL Server, deadlock monitoring is more effectively performed using Extended Events rather than the plain old alert on error 1205.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify. I want this for a different error number. It should be infrequent but a process could go wrong.